# Can anyone confirm that the "net" commands (net rpc, net ads, etc.) were removed from OS X Lion?

Tags: command-line, osx-lion

I just upgraded to OS X 10.7 Lion and soon realized that running `net rpc shutdown...` to reboot one of my Windows machines resulted in a "comand not found" error.  Indeed, it seems that `net`is just gone!  Can anyone think of a way to get this back? Is it perhaps in the OS X Lion Server bundle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "net" command is part of the Samba suite of utilities for interacting with Windows SMB network shares. Samba has shifted its licensing to the more restrictive GPLV3, which has prevented Apple from including it in Lion, and they have developed their own tools which omit a lot of legacy support for older implementations of SMB. Your best bet is probably to use MacPorts or Homebrew to install Samba yourself.

See the following links for more information:

- http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/03/23/inside_mac_os_x_10_7_lion_server_apple_replaces_samba_for_windows_networking_services.html
- http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/24/apple-to-drop-samba-networking-tools-from-lion/